# Raspberry Pi 4 With camera and PIR sensor - Script issue

Tags: sensor, raspberry-pi-os

**I have this code for detecting movement and recording said movement. This is my code:**

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

from picamera import PiCamera

import time

from datetime import datetime 

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

PIR_PIN = 7

GPIO.setup(PIR_PIN, GPIO.IN)

camera = PiCamera()

try:
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Ready")

    while True:
        if GPIO.input(PIR_PIN):

            print("Motion Detected!")

            timestamp = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
            video_name = 'VID_' + timestamp + '.h264'

            camera.start_recording(video_name)
            time.sleep(10)
            camera.stop_recording()
            camera.stop_preview()

            time.sleep(2)
            print("Ready")

        time.sleep(1)
```

**When I run the code I get this:**

```
Ready
Motion Detected!

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/david/pir-camera-case/examples/pir-camera-code/videoproject.py", line 24, in <module>
    camera.start_recording(video_name)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 1045, in start_recording
    encoder = self._get_video_encoder(

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 722, in _get_video_encoder
    return encoder_class(

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/encoders.py", line 600, in __init__
    super(PiVideoEncoder, self).__init__(

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/encoders.py", line 187, in __init__
    self._create_encoder(format, **options)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/encoders.py", line 724, in _create_encoder
    raise PiCameraValueError(
picamera.exc.PiCameraValueError: output resolution 4096x2160 exceeds macroblock limit (8192) for the selected H.264 profile and level
```

**I have been at this project for weeks setting this up and this is my last snag. Any help would be appreciated!!!**

Comment: The error message seems clear.  You need to correct the error.

Comment: I would try reducing the resolution!